# Why can I both Favorite and Ignore the same same tag?

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Is there a reason it is possible to  add the same tag to *both* the **Favorite tags** and **Ignored Tags** lists?  If a tag exists in both, what is the expected behavior - which gets precedence?

(**Update:** *A little more experimentation shows that tags in both list aren't showing up in my **Interesting** list, so Ignoring them may be taking precedence*)

[image: same tag in both lists]

Incidentally, since adding a new tag adds a new `<a>` to the DOM tree with its `id` attribute set to the tag name, it's possible to end up with non-unique `id`s when the tag is added in both places. (Obviously this seems like an unusual edge case, since the ids are only present until the page is refreshed.)

E.g adding the [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) produces a new element like:

```
<a id='sql' href='/questions/tagged/sql' class='post-tag user-tag...>sql</a>
```

Comment: Neither ends up getting precedence; you get the gray color of an interesting post, but the half-transparency of an ignored post

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Seems like although the CSS looks like a combination of both (like when 1 tag is favorited and another is ignored), when it exists in both I'm not seeing the questions in my Interesting lists. So the Ignore may be having a bigger effect.

Comment: Semantically, being able to have such a love-hate relationship with [crystal-reports] seems realistic.

Answer (score 5):

The system trusts you that you will be able to figure out that you probably only want a tag in *one* of those categories. Having the same tag in both doesn't really break anything on the site. All the highlighting and hiding done by your favorite and ignored tags is done client-side, so modifying it to check that it doesn't exist in one is just extra work that complicates the system and achieves absolutely nothing. If you really want to be odd and put a tag in both categories, you go right ahead and do that.

Other things you'll notice about favorite and ignored tags:

- The tags you enter there don't have to exist in the system.
- The tags you enter are not character-length-limited like normal tags.

Answer (score -3):

That is by design.

It is the same way like I can like tomatoes (when cooked) and hate them fresh.

Comment: There was a comment made to you, by I think it was Anna Lear, around 6-10 months ago that went something along the lines of "I've never met anyone who understood the way reputation works on MSO as much as you do". I would like to upvote that comment.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards now I am confused....

Comment: But the market doesn't actively show or hide tomatoes from you based on that preference.

Comment: @meta.michael the market does not listen to what I have to say. In this case the market is you. You are telling it that you both love and hate tomatoes and it does not know what to do with it, so it does what it was designed to do.