# Clarifying how Ignored Tags work

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I have two questions regarding Ignored Tags:

1. At the bottom of the [questions page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions), I see this message:

   > Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags:

   with a list of my Ignored Tags underneath.  Does that mean there are questions with those tags on the page, or is it just a confirmation that the system knows which tags I've ignored?
2. If an Ignored Tag and a Favorite Tag are on the same question, which takes precedence?

   Will I see the question because it has a favorite tag or will it be hidden because a tag is ignored? I think it's the latter because tags I do and don't like are frequently on the same questions, and I don't see them, but I'd appreciate clarification.

Comment: Related for #2: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161220/why-can-i-both-favorite-and-ignore-the-same-same-tag

Answer (score 6):

1. It means that the list of questions on the page would usually have questions with those tags on the page, but which the server is not serving up to you because of your preference.
2. If you don't hide ignored tags, they get a faded look. If, in that mode, there is a question with both ignored tags and favorite tags, it will get the favorite tag highlight but will also be faded... So essentially, there is no "precedence" - the styling for each is applied. However, given that a hidden question is, well... hidden, when that option is turned on, such a question will simply not be displayed to you.

Comment: #1 is wrong, I just made a quick test here, adding [tag:excel] to my ignored tags, and yet the box showed up even though there are no questions with this tag in the questions list. (Might a bug then?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - possibly my recollection is wrong then :)

Comment: Fair enough, happens to  the best... ;-)

Comment: Still bit confusing, e.g. using my previous example of excel tag, it would show only if going two years back, but the box is always there as far as I can see.

Comment: IIRC, the box only shows up if the list contains any tags that would be hidden from you. If there are no such questions in the list (say page X doesn't have those, it won't show the box, though if page X + 1 does have such questions, the box will show up).

Comment: OK, so [those](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxiGO.png) [are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcSsw.png) bugs?